# Using jQuery to list all checked values of a checkbox group. Works in FF and Chrome NOT in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

This code works like a champ in FF and Chrome to return a comma delimited list of checked values:

```
$('#lifesteps-group-0 :checked').each(function() {
  if (allSteps.length === 0) {
      allSteps = $(this).val();
}
else {
    allSteps = allSteps + ',' + $(this).val();
     }
});
```

Basically the lifesteps-group-0 div has all of the checkboxes in them. Like I said above it works beautifully in FF and Chrome, but only works for the first checkbox in IE.

Also here is the format of the checkbox group:

```
<div id="lifesteps-group-0">                        
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="lifesteps-0" id="lifesteps-0-22" value="22">
        <label for="ls-22" class="checkboxgroup">Began preparation as a missionary canidate</label>
    </div>                      
    <div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="lifesteps-0" id="lifesteps-0-23" value="23">
    <label for="ls-23" class="checkboxgroup">Began a small group, helped in a church plant</label>
     </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas oh jQuery GURUS?

Thanks,

Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) for this a bit cleaner and faster, like this:

```
var allSteps = $('#lifesteps-group-0 :checked').map(function() {
                 return this.value;
               }).get().join(', ');
```

If `allSteps` is an implied global (I don't see it declared in your code), it would throw some wonky issues in IE (like you're seeing), best to be safe when declaring it.

Comment: Nick, this code is having the same problem. Only the first item is working in IE. I copied the code just as you have it here. Any other ideas?

Comment: @resonantmedia -  Is the `lifesteps-group-0` ID in the page unique?

Comment: Yes it is unique. There is one update: Now instead of not even recognizing the values it is doing this if multiple values are selected: value1, , (in this case value 1 and two other values were selected).

Comment: @resonantmedia - I'm getting the right result here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/QCJda/ Where are you running this, inside a `click` handler? If so it should be `change` :)

Comment: The action is firing on a button click.

Comment: @resonantmedia - Do you have an example page?  Your markup works ok with my demo in IE above...something outside the question causing issues here.

Comment: Sure can I message you the URL some how? It is an internal site for metrics, I would rather not put it out here in public :-)

Comment: @resonantmedia - nrcraver, gmail

Comment: @resonantmedia - I'm not getting any problems here...try a hard clear of all cache on your end, no issues in IE8 for me.

Comment: You selected multiple items and they all appeared in the table above the checkboxes as a comma separated list (once you clicked "Add")?

Comment: @resonantmedia - The problem is here: `allSteps.split(',')` just change to `allSteps.split(', ')` or change my code to `.join(',')` so the delimiter matches, otherwise it's looking for a `label[for=ls- 3]` (with a space) and not finding it.

Answer (score 0):

Your checkboxes should have different IDs but same name.

Your selector should not be based on the ID.

Comment: It's a parent ID, there's nothing wrong with the selector...and it's radio buttons that should have the same name :)

Comment: @resonantmedia, my answer might be wrong but I remember experiencing problems with jQuery on IE because it has strict rules about the same id attribute. The checkboxes shouldn't have the same name (these are for radioboxes) but I modififed the selector. You can check that out.

Comment: @Nick Craver, yep that part about having the same name is wrong. haha. sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

try initializing the `allSteps` variable

it worked in IE8 as given; when i try with

```
var allSteps='';
```